# How to select the label In coreplot

Tags: core-plot

I wanted to get the axisLabel value by clicking on it to plot a line graph? How can achieve this? Is there any possibilities to select each label value?. I have tried plot space delegate method of `-(BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldHandlePointingDeviceDownEvent:(id)event atPoint:(CGPoint)point`.By this i can able get bound values only. what would be the best solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to click the axis labels and not plot data labels?

Comment: Hi Eric, If i am not clear, please bear me.My Y axis label Values are 175,176,177,178..... with majorInterVel 5. When i press on one of the above value my console says the `Point` is `NSEvent: type=LMouseDown loc=(772,203) time=5310.5 flags=0x100 win=0x10022a340 winNum=317 ctxt=0x0 evNum=552 click=1 buttonNumber=0 pressure=1`.location are changing every press. How can i get the value of 175,176,...?

Comment: Please give me a solutions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert the point from the coordinate system of the graph layer to the plot area:

   ```
   CGPoint pointInPlotArea = [space.graph convertPoint:interactionPoint
                                               toLayer:space.graph.plotAreaFrame.plotArea];
   ```
2. Convert the point to data coordinates:

   ```
   NSDecimal plotPoint[2];
   [space plotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:pointInPlotArea];
   ```

   or

   ```
   double plotPoint[2];
   [space doublePrecisionPlotPoint:plotPoint forPlotAreaViewPoint:pointInPlotArea];
   ```

Comment: Thanks Eric. It helped me. Likewise, Can I get the coordinate values from the plot area without touch, only mouse over the graph?

Comment: If you can get the mouseMoved event, you can extract the interaction point from the event and convert it as shown above. Look at the code for the hosting view to see how to convert the point to graph layer coordinates.